# Balls and Bins Confusion

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, balls-in-bins

I’m struggling to wrap my head around a basic balls and bins question:

So say I have $12$ indistinguishable balls and $6$ distinguishable bins. $3$ balls are already in $3$ different bins. The next $9$ balls are put into the $6$ bins randomly. What is the probability that each bin has at least one ball?

I approached this problem by dividing the number of ways to put $6$ balls in $6$ bins by the number of ways to put $9$ balls in $6$ bins. Thus:
$$\frac {\binom {11}{6}}{\binom {14}{9}} = \frac {462}{2002}$$

What if we start with $2$ balls in one bin and $1$ ball in another bin instead of $3$ balls in $3$ different bins?

Then I get $\frac {\binom {10}{5}}{\binom {14}{9}} = \frac {252}{2002}$.

Is this right? I assumed that the probability would be higher.

Comment: Sorry, why are you considering $6$ balls into $6$ bins?

Comment: Should stress:  Stars and Bars is a terrible way to address probability questions.  That's because the patterns you are counting are not equally probable.  Say you are putting two indistinct balls into two distinct urns.  Then $(1,1)$ is twice as likely as $(2,0)$.  I think you'll want Inclusion Exclusion here.

Comment: @lulu OP is placing $3$ of the $9$ balls in $3$ bins that do not have balls to start with and then placing remaining $6$ balls in $6$ bins ensuring none of the bins remain empty. So OP seems to be correctly applying stars and bars method but it is of course not correct method here as you mentioned in your next comment.

Comment: @MathLover  But of course that multiply counts distributions in which more than one ball goes into one of the would-be empty bins.  It's just not a good method.

Comment: @lulu yes, absolutely agree

Comment: @lulu but (1,1), (2,0) and (0,2) are all equally likely, and stars and bars would count them separately. That is why $x_1+x_2=2$ has $3$ solutions and not $2$.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta  No, they are not.  If each ball is equally likely to go in each urn, then the probability both go in the first (or both go in the second) is $\frac 14$ while the probability that one goes in the first and the other in the second is $\frac 12$.  There are three solutions, of course, but they are not equi-probable.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I think here OP is right and @Math Lover is incorrect. Let us take the simple case of 2 urns and 2 balls, with one ball in urn 1 already. Then probability of atleast 1 ball in each is 0.5. However, if we proceed via Math Lover's method, we get $\frac {(2^2-\binom {1}{1} 1^2)}{2^2}=\frac 34$. Perhaps I'm wrong, but where?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta you are applying P.I.E incorrectly. It should be $\frac {2^2-\binom {2}{1} 1^2}{2^2}$

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta $99 \%$ chance that applying stars and bars would be incorrect in a probability question. There are situations where it would work but one has to be absolutely sure on that before applying stars and bars. In this case, it is surely incorrect - it is a much debated topic and you can find quite a bit of posts and literature on it. We can discuss further in chat later, if you are interested.

Comment: @Math Lover Since we are putting one ball in one of two bins, wouldn’t it be (2-1)/2?

Comment: @RebeccaDeitch that is correct - the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$. The point is about the method.

Comment: @Math Lover Thanks! I posted a follow-up to your answer, and I was wondering if you could look at it to see if I was applying the method correctly

Comment: @Math Lover yes, I'd like to clear up a few things. However, I've never used chat. How do I do it?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta see if you are able to join this room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127996/stars-and-bars. you may notify me from there by tagging me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question seeks the *probability* that each bin has at least one ball. You should not be using stars and bars method to calculate probability. Treat each ball as if they were distinguishable.

Now we are given that $3$ balls are already there in $3$ different bins. So we are left with placing $9$ balls in $6$ bins and each ball is placed in one of the bins randomly. So sample space is $6^9$.

Say for example, bins $1, 2, 3$ have a ball each to start with. So  favorable outcomes are those where bins $4, 5, 6$ receive at least a ball each from $9$ balls. The best way to go about it is to apply Principle of Inclusion Exclusion.

So desired probability is,

$ \displaystyle \left [6^9 - {3 \choose 1} 5^9 + {3 \choose 2} 4^9 - {3 \choose 3} 3^9 \right] / 6^9 = \frac{830845}{1679616}$

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your explanation— I was really confused about why my answer was so low! For the second scenario, I got: (6^9 - C(4, 1)*5^9 + C(4, 2)*4^9 - C(4, 3)*3^9 + C(4, 4)*2^9)/6^9 = 3759840/10077696 ~ 37.31%. Does this sound right?

Comment: @RebeccaDeitch I checked and it is correct. I get the same 
 result. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! As an extension, I was wondering how to calculate the probability for putting exactly 6 balls in one bin. If we start with 2 balls in one bin and 1 ball in another, I calculated C(9,4)*(1/6)^4*(5/6)^5 + C(9,5)*(1/6)^5*(5/6)^4 + 4*C(9,6)*(1/6)^6*(5/6)^3 = 5.11%. Does this approach work?

Comment: @ Math Lover Ah, thanks! I tried to upvote but I didn’t have enough reputation.

Comment: Coming to your question, when you say one of the bins has exactly $6$ bins, is it one of the four bins or any of the $6$ bins?

Comment: Any of the 6 bins— I tried to account for all 6 possibilities but I’m not sure I did so correctly

Comment: @RebeccaDeitch yes you cannot upvote till you have certain reputation, don't worry about that. upvoting or accepting an answer is not necessary in any case, though a good practice.

Comment: No, I only considered the condition that one bin had to have exactly 6 balls. But now that I think of it, did I double-count the case in which there are 6 balls in each of the two bins that already had balls?

Comment: if it is allowed for two bins to have $6$ balls then you are overcounting once. Subtract ${9 \choose 4} / 6^9$. Rest is all correct.